# Making a 4 digit pin in tkinker

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with tkinker python and trying to make a 4 digit pin lock screen. Im trying to draw white squares for each digit and I can not figure out how to manipulate the api in a way to get a perfect square. What am I doing wrong, how can I do this? Here is my code

```html
from tkinter import *

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.configure(background="#262626")
        master.wm_iconbitmap('moth.ico')
        master.title("Moth")
        master.geometry("800x600")
        self.widgets()
        self.pack()
    def widgets(self):
        backGroundCanvas = Canvas(self, bg='#262626', width=800, height=600)
        backGroundCanvas.focus_set()
        backGroundCanvas.pack()

        #create pin
        backGroundCanvas.create_rectangle(self, meme=1)

root = Tk()
app = app(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a square rectangle with white fill.  [This](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html) is a good reference.  I removed the reference to an icon I don't have.

```
from tkinter import *

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.configure(background="#262626")
        master.title("Moth")
        master.geometry("800x600")
        self.widgets()
        self.pack()
    def widgets(self):
        backGroundCanvas = Canvas(self, bg='#262626', width=800, height=600)
        backGroundCanvas.focus_set()
        backGroundCanvas.pack()

        #create pin
        backGroundCanvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, fill='white')

root = Tk()
app = app(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if I wanted to position the square would I just need to move the canvas?

Comment: @Hedron change the object's coordinates that you want to move.